# Is there a way to reset IIS 7.5 to factory settings?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I modified a lot of options in IIS, and would like to reset its settings to default.

I already tried installing/reinstalling it. After the reinstall, it still had the site I created. It was still breaking on the setting I made to the DefaultWebSite.

People suggested uninstalling Windows Process Activation Service first, but it seems like it wasn't installed anyway, so I can't really uninstall it.

How can I reset this installation of IIS back to an out-of-the-box state?

Comment: Which settings are you worried about? What's preventing you from creating a new site? There aren't many options to tweak on IIS itself, but the majority are at the site level.

Answer (score 25):

You need to uninstall IIS (Internet Information Services) but the key thing here is to make sure you **uninstall the Windows Process Activation Service** or otherwise your ApplicationHost.config will be still around. When you uninstall WAS then your configuration will be cleaned up and you will truly start with a fresh new IIS (and all data/configuration will be lost).

Comment: step by step process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792419/iis-7-configuration-file-is-not-well-formed-xml/17792990#17792990

Answer (score 13):

There are automatic backup under %systemdrive%\inetpub\history but it may not help much if you already made lots of changes.

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/24/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration.aspx

You will have to regularly back up manually using appcmd.

If you try to reinstall IIS, please first uninstall IIS and WAS via Add/Remove Programs, and then delete all existing files under C:\inetpub and C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv directories. Then you can install again cleanly.

**WARN: beginners on IIS are not recommended to execute the steps above without a full backup of the system. The steps should be executed with caution and good understanding of IIS. If you are not capable of or you have doubt, make sure you open a support case with Microsoft via http://support.microsoft.com and consult.**

Comment: Deleting C:\inetpub and C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv directories destroyed what hope I had left for my IIS and it seems impossible to reinstall.

Comment: @FredrikC, it is not deleting the directories that makes it impossible to reinstall. That's totally another issue, which you might learn from my blog posts, such as http://www.lextm.com/2011/02/if-you-cannot-installuninstall-iis-7.html

Comment: Good tip. In my case the IIS install was not critical and I had not made a lot of changes. So `appcmd.exe list backup` helped me locate a good backup. Then a simple `appcmd.exe restore backup "the backup name"` did the trick. Saved me from having to do a reinstall! Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was going to the article someone else had already mentioned, but keying on this piece:

> application.config.backup is not created by automatic backup. The backup files are in %systemdrive%\inetpub\history directory. Automatic backup is also a Vista SP1 and above feature. More information can be found in this blog post, http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/24/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration.aspx

I was able to find backups of my settings from when I had first installed IIS, and just copy and replace the files in the inetsrv\config directory.

Source: http://forums.iis.net/t/1085990.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is one way that I have used my self. Go to `Control Panel\Programs\Turn Windows features on or off` then uninstall IIS and all of its components completely. I restart windows but I'm not sure if it's required or not. Then install it again from the same path.

Comment: This works. Though this will result in fresh installation of IIS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This link has some useful suggestions: 
http://forums.iis.net/t/1085990.aspx

> It depends on where you have the config settings stored. By default
>   IIS7 will have all of it's configuration settings stored in a file
>   called "ApplicationHost.Config". If you have delegation configured
>   then you will see site/app related config settings getting written to
>   web.config file for the site/app. With IIS7 on vista there is an
>   automatica backup file for master configuration is created. This file
>   is called "application.config.backup" and it resides inside
>   "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" You could rename this file to
>   applicationHost.config and replace it with the applicationHost.config
>   inside the config folder. IIS7 on server release will have better
>   configuration back up story, but for now I recommend using APPCMD to
>   backup/restore your configuration on regualr basis. Example: APPCMD
>   ADD BACK "MYBACKUP"   Another option (really the last option) is to
>   uninstall/reinstall IIS along with WPAS (Windows Process activation
>   service).

Comment: I saw that post myself, and I think I had fiddled around that area as well, because I dont see that file there!

Comment: Also, I'm using Windows 7, not Windows Vista.

Comment: How about this one: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/111902-how-can-i-reset-iis-7-running-on-windows-7-to-default

Comment: that didn't work either. how do you feel about me copying files from a system that has IIS untouched? what files should be copied?

Comment: The forum post is not correct by saying "application.config.backup", as it never exists.

Answer (score -1):

**Resetting IIS**

1. On the computer that is running Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web Server components, open a command prompt as an administrator as follows:

a. From the Start menu, choose All Programs, and then choose Accessories.
b. Right-click Command Prompt, and then choose Run as administrator.

2. At the command prompt, type the following command to change to the Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 folder, and then press Enter.
3. cd\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
4. At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press Enter.
5. aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
6. At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press Enter.
   iisreset